# Will 'typedef logic' generate a register when using it instead of a 'wire', in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, register-transfer-level, type-definition

Having the following SystemVerilog code:

```
module my_module(
  input  wire [31:0] my_net
);
  ...
endmodule
...
...
wire [31:0] my_net;

assign my_net = ...;

my_module m(my_net);
```

What are the consequences (at synthesis time) of change the `my_net` declaration by:

```
typedef logic [31:0] my_net_t; // This is actually no longer a net, but a variable.

module my_module(
  input  my_net_t my_net
);
  ...
endmodule

my_module m(my_net);
...
...
wire [31:0] my_net;

assign my_net = ...;

my_module m(my_net);
```

I mean, `logic` is a variable, not a net, therefore, will the synthesizer generate a register for `my_net`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incorrect. `logic` is a data type that can be applied to a variable *or* net.

```
input  wire [31:0] my_net
input  my_net_t my_net
```

are implicitly the same as

```
input  wire logic [31:0] my_net
input  wire my_net_t my_net
```

When internal to a module

```
logic v;
wire w;
```

are implicitly

```
var logic v;
wire logic W;
```

But regardless of `my_net` being a variable or net, a continuous assignment to `my_net` does not create a register.

Answer (score 1):

No.
Continuous assignment using

```
assign my_net = RHS;
```

does not infer registers.